# Supplying argument by exec function in php

Tags: php, r, command-line-arguments

I am using following php code to run a script of R language.

```
echo "<form action='rtest1.php' method='get'>";
echo "Number values to generate: <input type='text' name='N' />";
echo "<input type='submit' />";
echo "</form>";

if(isset($_GET['N']))
{
  $N = $_GET['N'];

  // execute R script from shell
  // this will save a plot at temp.png to the filesystem
  $result=array();
  $int='';
  exec("D:\\R-2.14.0\\bin\\Rscript.exe D:\\wamp\\www\\R\\test.R 7 2 1");


}
```

Here is the sample  code of my Rscript

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE);

    #assign data path
    data_path <- "D:\\wamp\\www\\R";

    #assign valus to the following three percent
    train_per <- args[1];
    test_per <- args[2];
    val_per <- args[3];
```

I want to pass the values 7,2 and 1 to the Rscript from the php code

```
exec("D:\\R-2.14.0\\bin\\Rscript.exe D:\\wamp\\www\\R\\test.R 7 2 1");
```

So how can i do this.Please help

Comment: It looks fine (except for the outer parentheses), do you get an error when you run the code? If it's "syntax error, unexpected ';', it's the outer parentheses that's most likely causing it.

Comment: I must ask this one: why don't you install RApache? This approach tends to be code-injection friendly. =/

Answer (score 1):

To get the different parameters values in your R script you can do :

```
myarg <- commandArgs() #get all arguments from console
n <- myarg[length(myarg)] #number of arguments
tmp<-strsplit(n,",") # parsing of the arguments (here the convention to separate the arg is the comma , )

folderPath <- tmp[[1]][1]; # value of the 1st argument
paramPath <- tmp[[1]][2]; # value of the 2nd argument  
dataPath <- tmp[[1]][3]; # value of the 3rd argument
```

Comment: the adaptation for your sample R script should be like : `myarg <- commandArgs() #get all arguments from console`

`n <- myarg[length(myarg)] #number of arguments`

`tmp<-strsplit(n," ") # parsing of the arguments (here the convention to separate the arg is the space)`

`train_per <- as.numeric(tmp[[1]][1]); # value of the 1st argument`

`test_per <- as.numeric(tmp[[1]][2]); # value of the 2nd argument ` 

`val_per <- as.numeric(tmp[[1]][3]); # value of the 3rd argument`

Answer (score 1):

You've done it, except you may wish to do as.numeric(args[1]) and so on to convert the character "7" to a numeric 7.

Comment: it is still not working .Am i missing any other line of code in R.Can i try running this R script from Dos Prompt if yes then how

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
myarg <- commandArgs()

tmp <- strsplit(myarg," ")

arg1 <- tmp[[1]][1]; # value of the 1st argument
arg2 <- tmp[[2]][1]; # value of the 2nd argument  
arg3 <- tmp[[3]][1]; # value of the 3rd argument
```